# “Cannot read from source disk.” Is there a bad sector on SSD?

Tags: ssd

Today I’ve tried to copy some files from my SSD drive to a external hard drive. But on some files I get an error:

> “Cannot read from source disk.”

I try to copy these files one by one, but I’ve get the same error. I remember that when this error occur on HDD, one of the reason was a bad sector.

What about the SSD? Do they have bad sectors too? Or this problem has another reason?

Comment: Run the SSD manufacturer's drive test.. Time to replace your SSD

Comment: @John The ssd is used  for less than a year. Do the SSD fail so fast ?

Comment: It is probably not the best quality SSD.  My Lenovo laptops use top quality drives (best Samsung among them) . The oldest is 7 years old and no errors.  You may have gotten a bad drive.  No matter - my answer still applies

Comment: @John Samsung !!!!!

Comment: Mean time to failure is an average and does not apply to each and every drive

Comment: Please edit your question to add more details: What model of SSD is this? It is a Samsung, but what exact model? And what exact system is this being used in?

Comment: so yes, it is possible the disk is dead. I had a samsung SSD fail last year and it was less than a year old. its important to understand that HDDs and SSDs operate differently, and thus they fail differently. SSDs tend to fail all at once, with little advanced warning, while HDDs usually degrade more slowly and give more warnings of their impending demise. SSDs do have "bad sectors" (cells really) but i don't believe that they require offline-reallocation, so the occurence of a bad block should be transparent to the user if successful.

Comment: HDD's often will have an issue with one sector of a platter, whereas SSD's are more apt to become read-only, *if* they fail gracefully, or die all at once. They're provisioned for a finite number of write cycles, and then fail. Some applications can destroy an SSD, e.g., https://www.tomsguide.com/news/windows-10-update-could-kill-your-ssd-what-you-need-to-know and https://www.salvagedata.com/ssd-failures-common-causes-and-main-symptom/